# How do React Native components avoid recursive state updates?

Tags: react-native

Consider the TextInput component of React Native. It has a prop called `value`. I set the value to `this.state.text`.

It also has a prop `onChangeText`, which I set to `(text) => {this.setState({text: text})`.

Setting the state will cause the view to re-render, which will in turn trigger `setValue` on the component.

This doesn't cause any sort of recursion or undesired behavior with stock components. However, in building my own text input component, I'm finding that using `state` in `value` and in `onChangeText` causes native input events to re-render the view and call `setValue`.

i.e user types on keyboard, native module emits `onChangeText` event, JavaScript component receives event and updates state, state change causes re-render, re-render calls setValue on the native component, and the native component swaps out the text with the value received from the initial event (the same value).

The problem is, when you set the text on an iOS or Android native text component, it resets the cursor. So I tried putting in a conditional `if(newText != currentText) {setText(newText)}`, and this works when you type slow, but when you type fast, things get chaotic and you can't predict the order of events.

I looked at how the React Native authors handle this in their own text component, and they seem to be using some sort of counter ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L819) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java#L679)) to synchronize events, but I couldn't keep up with the logic as it was all over the place.

For now, my solution is to not use `state` in the render function, but then my component depends on `render` not being called unexpectedly to function properly, and that's just a disaster waiting to happen.

Any insight as how to better design a component like this, or how RN components get around this issue?